# Get Instagram access token with out reloading page

Tags: javascript, jquery, authentication, oauth-2.0, instagram

My requirement is as follows.

I am at page `create.html` i want to fire a popup saying `Login with Instagram`. When user click that popup. i want to authenticate user on a popup window like facebook and get the access token back on the same page with out reloading. As i am appending pics i will get from instagram in a div already containing pics from facebook which will lost if i refresh.

I am successfully firing request and getting that access token. But i am not sure how do i grab that token like success function in ajax request.

req:
`https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=XXX&redirect_uri=http://localhost:3000/auth/instagram/callback&response_type=code`

res:
`http://localhost:3000/auth/instagram/callback?code=XXXX`

How do i grab that `code=XXXX` in my create.html?

I can only use javascript and jquery. Nodejs? no!

I tried using this library. `https://github.com/Instagram/instagram-javascript-sdk` but its giving me error. `{"code": 400, "error_type": "OAuthException", "error_message": "JS login temporarily disabled"}`.

If there is any way to get this token like facebook.(below)

```
    FB.login(
        function (response) {
            if (response.authResponse) {
            access_token =   FB.getAuthResponse()['accessToken'];
            new facebookLogin(access_token);
            }
        }
    );
```

or any way to grab that url `code=XXXX`. kindly help me out.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just use window.location.search on your callback page to access the query string and parse out the code parameter.

Comment: The thing is, i dont want such page. i dont want to use another page.

Comment: On your create page, after you have launched the popup window you can use setTimeout to monitor the url in the popup using location.href to detect if you have navigated to the callback url. Then you can extract the code, close the window and continue. Beware that you are using an authorization code grant here. You will need to perform a post to the token endpoint of instagram to exchange the code for the final access token.